# How to solve Custom Drawer Component Touchable onPress Screen switching not Working in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react-native project, I am using one **Drawer navigation** where I have added  two drawer items, which are working well by pressing. Below the Items I have declared one **TouchableOpacity** and inside that I have added one Text "log out". Now, by pressing the Logout I want change the screen to **loginScreen** and set the **AsyncStorage** value of token to empty string.

Here's a Screen Shot of my Drawer navigation-

[image]

And here's the code of my Drawer navigation component-

```
const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (
  <ScrollView>
    <SafeAreaView
      style={styles.container}
      forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />

    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
            {
            AsyncStorage.setItem("token", '')
            }

          }
        }
    >


     <Text>Log out</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>

    </SafeAreaView>
  </ScrollView>
);

const navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    NoteMeHome,
    MakeNote,


  },
  {
    drawerType: 'back',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerWidth: 200,
    drawerBackgroundColor: 'orange',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
  }
);
```

So, After running the project whenever I press the log out Text it shows the following error-

[image]

So, it would be very nice if somebody helps me find out the problem and help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'this' and pass the props to the component when you call it or create your component as a class instead of a functional component and in the constructor pass the props, like:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}
```

so the props will be accessible by this.props...

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
```

With:

```
contentComponent:(props)=> <CustomDrawerContentComponent navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

There is another solution:

You can easily export your `CustomDrawerContentComponent` and when you export it, wrap it with `withNavigation from 'react-navigation'` wrapper like that

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
    your code here ...
export default withNavigation(CustomDrawerContentComponent)
```